# My anet a2 auto-homes incorrectly

Tags: printer-building, desktop-printer, anet-a2

I just made my anet a2, and when I hit auto-home it goes off the board makes a loud clacking sound going down a bit (under the heat bed but off to the side). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Your limit switches are not working properly - they should always hit.

Do the following steps:

1. Move axis in all possible directions, both positive and negative;
2. Check limit switch wiring;
3. Limit switch output.